# Capturing a screenshot using window.scroll with high DPI settings

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, dpi, cefsharp

I'm using `CefSharp 55.0.0` `WinForms`.

In order to take screenshots in `CefSharp`, I scroll the webpage using `window.scroll` within JavaScript and take an image of the current viewport. Once that has completed, it is then stitched back together again. This works fine for monitors that have their `DPI` setting set to `100%`. However, when the monitor has a `DPI` greater than `100%` screenshots do not work as expected and miss content.

**Image 1 - 100%**

[image]

**Image 2 - 150%**

[image]

Compare Image 1 to Image 2. While they both (practically) have the same width and height, Image 2 is missing a large portion of the content, compared to a perfect Image 1.

When `DPI` settings are above `100%`, how can I correctly scroll and capture a screenshot that ensures I obtain everything it would if settings were at `100%`?

**Other details**

The application has the correct DPI aware settings in the`app.manifest` file and `Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();` has been called in the `Main` method within `Program.cs`.

**Screenshot Code (abridged)**

```
int scrollHeight = GetDocHeight(); //some javascript that calcs the height of the document
int viewportHeight = ClientRectangle.Size.Height; 
int viewportWidth = ClientRectangle.Size.Width;
int count = 0;
int pageLeft = scrollHeight;
bool atBottom = false;

while (!atBottom)
{
    if (pageLeft > viewportHeight)
    {
        await GetBrowser().MainFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync("(function() { window.scroll(0," + (count * viewportHeight) + "); })();"); //I think the issue lies here
        count++;
        await PutTaskDelay();
        using (Bitmap image = GetCurrentViewScreenshot())
        {
            //just a class that saves the partial images to a disk cache
            cache.AddImage(count, image);
        }
    }
    else 
    {

        await GetBrowser().MainFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync("(function() { window.scrollBy(0," + pageLeft + "); })();");

        atBottom = true;
        count++;

        await PutTaskDelay();
        Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(new Point(0, viewportHeight - pageLeft), new Size(viewportWidth, pageLeft));

        using (Bitmap src = GetCurrentViewScreenshot())
        using (Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height))
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            cache.AddImage(count, target);
        }

    }
    pageLeft = pageLeft - viewportHeight;
}
```

**Current View Screenshot Method**

```
private Bitmap GetCurrentViewScreenshot()
{
    int width, height;
    width = ClientRectangle.Width;
    height = ClientRectangle.Height;


    using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height))
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            Point p, upperLeftDestination;
            Point upperLeftSource = new Point(0, 0);
            p = new Point(0, 0);
            upperLeftSource = PointToScreen(p);
            upperLeftDestination = new Point(0, 0);
            Size blockRegionSize = ClientRectangle.Size;
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(upperLeftSource, upperLeftDestination, blockRegionSize);

        }
        return new Bitmap(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `viewportHeight` to scroll the page is likely causing problems as your comment suggests. You could mess around with scaling that value to match the browsers height or simply as the browser what it's viewable width/height is. I'd also be looking at refactoring the code to reduce duplication. I'd also make `GetDocHeight` a proper async method, (avoid using `Wait()`).

Comment: Thank you @amaitland. While I'm back looking at screenshots, I will be giving it big a refactor. This code was originally created for the `WebBrowser` control that provided neater properties to the underlying `Document` (about the only good thing about that awful control), and when I converted to `CefSharp` some things didn't quite get the attention they deserved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

While not a perfect solution, I found a workaround that involves setting the `force-device-scale-factor` flag to `1` in `CefSettings`. It's not perfect because the browser isn't scaled on high `DPI` displays, potentially making text hard to read for users. However, it does fix my more pressing issue of missing data in screenshots.

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("force-device-scale-factor", "1");
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

This question is still open for better suggestions, if there are any. :-)